# Regression coefficient on a triangle using geometry

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, regression-coefficients, geometry

I am encountering a question as follows:

Let $X, Y$ be two independent uniform random variable on $(0,1)$. We consider the regression model $Y = \beta_1 X + \beta_0$, given the restriction that $X + Y > 1$. We want to find $\beta_1$.

Let us call $U = X|X + Y > 1$, $V = Y|X+Y > 1$. Then we could compute the density of $U$ and $V$ by doing conditional probability, and $\beta_1 = \frac{Cov(U,V)}{Var(U)}$, $\beta_0$ could be found by plugging in the mean of $U$ and $V$. The final answer should be $\beta_1 = -\frac{1}{2}$.

My question is: how to compute $\beta_1$ based on geometry? If we draw the graph, we could see that we are doing a right-top triangle within the unit square $[0,1] \times [0,1]$. We could also know the center of the triangle is $(\frac{2}{3}, \frac{2}{3}) = (E[U], E[V])$. Is there a way that we could visualize the $\beta_1$ should be $-\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Because $X+Y\gt 1,$ these variables are *not* independent.  Are you saying you wish to truncate the distribution of $(X,Y)$ to this region and regress $Y$ on $X$?  If so, you don't need to compute any densities really: you can fit this regression simply by *looking* at a drawing of this region and invoking definitions.  Specifically: what is the expectation of $Y$ conditional on $X$?

Comment: @whuber I think two ideas are the same. Let us consider your truncation interpretation, to fit the line, intuitively I would take y = x, am I correct?

Comment: Intuitively you should take the fitted value of $Y$ to be its conditional expectation given $X:$ that's what regression means.  At each possible value of $X,$ how are the values of $Y$ distributed?  Argue that because each conditional distribution is symmetric, its expectation is its midrange.  You can see the midranges in the diagram.

Comment: @whuber Thank you so much, I got the idea!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because $(X,Y)$ has a uniform distribution over the triangle shown, the expectation of $Y$ conditional on $X$ evidently splits the lower and upper boundaries of the triangle, shown as the dotted line $y = 1 - x/2:$

[image]

That's the regression of $Y$ on $X.$  Because it *happens* to be a linear function, it's also the (Ordinary Least Squares, or "OLS") linear regression.

---

**We can prove this from first principles.** The density function (supported in the blue triangle of the diagram) is

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 2\mathcal I(0\le x\le 1,\ 1-x \le y\le 1).$$

We will need the first and second moments, as always, so let's calculate them now.  By symmetry $X$ and $Y$ have the same expectation,

$$E[Y] = E[X] = \iint x f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm d x\, \mathrm d y = 2 \int_0^1\int_{1-x}^1 x \,\mathrm d x\, \mathrm d y = \frac{2}{3}.$$

Similarly

$$E[Y^2] = E[X^2] = \frac{1}{2}$$

and

$$E[XY] = \frac{5}{12}.$$

The least squares objective is the average squared deviation between $Y$ and $\alpha + \beta X$ for unknown parameters to be determined:

$$\Lambda = \iint (y - (\alpha + \beta x))^2\,f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm dy.$$

This is a differentiable function of the parameters (which can be any real numbers) and the differentiation can be carried out under the integral sign, telling us that

$$\Lambda_\alpha = 2\iint y - (\alpha + \beta x)\,f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy = 2\left(E[Y] - \alpha - \beta E[X]\right)$$

and

$$\Lambda_\beta =  2\iint x(y - (\alpha + \beta x))\,f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy = 2\left(E[XY] - \alpha E[X] - \beta E[X^2]\right).$$

Equating both with zero gives all possible critical points.  Plugging in the expectations computed previously gives

$$0 = 2\left(\frac{2}{3} - \alpha - \beta \frac{2}{3}\right)$$

and

$$0 = 2\left(\frac{5}{12} - \frac{2}{3} - \beta \frac{1}{2}\right).$$

This system of linear equations (the *Normal equations* of OLS) has the unique solution (easily found)

$$(\alpha,\beta) = (1, -1/2),$$

as we saw in the diagram.